# Why rinetd is working locally but not working remotly?

Tags: linux-networking

```
/etc/rinetd.conf
0.0.0.0 443 10.30.224.7 636
allow *

>lsop -i|grep rinetd
rinetd    27099        root    4u  IPv4 2553556       TCP *:https (LISTEN)
```

Also `iptables -L -n` returns nothings.

Still, if I try to telnet to localhost (or using the server IP) to port 443 it will work but if I try the same from another machine it will fail with `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

So, there is something on that port but it does not want to respond.

What am I missing?

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an error? If so, what error?

Comment: If the connection times out, that means no response is coming back from the network. That's almost always caused by a firewall. (Probably a software firewall on the destination machine.)

Comment: This would be very award as all machines I tested can connect directly to the destination one `10.30.224.7:636`.

Comment: Try changing 0.0.0.0 to your server IP address

Comment: @ManulaWaidyanatha I already tried this but there is no difference.

Comment: Have you actually got a service that is listening to telnet connections on port 443 on the receiving server. You can't telnet into a listening HTTPS server - it would naturally timeout.

Comment: In fact it is not a HTTP server on the other end. It is a LDAPS server which does respond to telnet. I am trying to use 443 port because this port is allowed by the corporate firewall. Still, I do want to mention that all these tests I made were not using any firewall, yet!

Comment: Does the telnet message come back right away or hang?  Can you use netcat to create a listener on 443 and test telnet again? It sounds like a firewall issue still.

Comment: depending on your firewall it might have an intrusion detection, and your "non-https" traffic gets blocked. Can you use the service from another station in the same subnet, possibly without any involvement of additional hardware?

Comment: any log in rinetd.log file?

Answer (score 1):

"Connection timed out" usually indicates a firewall is in place. If it wasn't the firewall, it would say "Connection refused" or something similar (in case service isn't accessible). Run `service iptables stop` and if you are on RH based OS be sure to check SELinux and disable it for the time of debugging with `setenforce 0`.